# Data factory SQL connection String with keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I exported arm template from Datafactory V2, when Importing the template it is asking me to manually enter SQL database connection string. To minimize the human interaction I made the following changes.

```
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/myFactory')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "connectionString": "[concat('Server=tcp:',parameters('sqlServerName'),'.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=', parameters('sqlDatabaseName'), ';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=',parameters('sqlServerUserName'),';Password=(password)',';MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30')]",
                    "password": {
                        "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                        "store": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureKeyVault1",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        },
                        "secretName": "sql-password"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/AzureKeyVault1')]"
            ]
        },
```

So currently when deploying to Datafactory V2 and test connection to this SQL server, I got

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'tcp:mysqlserver.database.windows.net,1433', 
Database: 'mydatabase', User: 'admin'. Check the linked service configuration
is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
Login failed for user 'admin'., SqlErrorNumber=18456,
```

If I manually input all the connections in the portal UI, I can easily connect to the database and test successfully so it is not a firewall issue.

Then I think there could be 2 issue:

1.how the password from keyvault is consumed in the connectionstring. I didn't find much information about it online.

2. When I open the created Sql Linked service, I notice the Fully qualified domain name is missing,If i manually add it in then the connection works.

[The SQL connection UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK57t.png)

Comment: Doe the password have any special characters? This can cause issues when retrieving it via this method.  Also what does the audit log show for key vault? Was the credential actually retrieved by Data Factory

Comment: The password does have '+' and '='. How can I handle this type of issue if password contains special characters? The credential should be retrieved, I did add permission for datafactory to access Keyvault, And when connecting using the UI as the picture I attached, I can easily establish a connection. I just have to manually type in the Fully qualified domain name... which is another question, why is that field not populated from arm template?

Comment: + and = should be alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing this as an alternative answer/approach.

Store the connection string in it's entirety in Key Vault. If doing this then the reference would look like:

```
{
  "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/',parameters('connectionNameAdventureWorks'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": {
        "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
        "store": {
          "referenceName": "[variables('azkDataAnalyticsReferenceName')]",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "secretName": "[variables('azkAdventureWorksSecretName')]"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": [
     "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/',variables('azkDataAnalyticsReferenceName'))]" 
  ]
}
```

And even more secure approach would be to add Data Factory as a [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity) and then [run a sql script to add the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql) If doing this then all there is no need for any credentials to be passed at all.

One downside is if the DataFactory is deleted and recreated then the managed identity permissions would need to be reassigned to the sql database.

Comment: So please take a look at the picture I attached, It so happens that if I manually add ":mysqlserver.database.windows.net" at the Fully qualified domain name section then the whole thing will be working. Do you have any idea why the Fully qualified domain name is missing?